# Can I use Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN font in a UIWebView screen?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I know that the "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN" font family is available in a standard iOS display, but I want to use it via CSS in UIWebView display.  Is this possible?  When I tried it in my "font family", it was not available.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use the Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN font as I had seen it used in Windows and Mac HTML displays. I just needed to use the font as it exists on iOS (e.g., "HiraKakuProN-W3").